# How to get existing orchestration instance in DTF?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

NB - I am not using Azure durable functions. Just the durable task framework.

I have a scenario where in I need to run an orchestration and in one of the tasks check for a flag. If the flag is true I move forward with the orchestration. If its false I put some information in a db (orchestration execution id, input data etc) and halt the orchestration.

I have a Service Fabric Actor that would run every 24 hours and check the entries in the db for the halted orchestration. It would then check for the aforementioned flag for each orchestration (based on some identifier it would call an external API and get this information). If the flag is true it would need to resume the orchestration. If after 14 retrials the flag still remains false it would need to delete the orchestration.

I was thinking about following [DTF Waiting for external events](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/wiki/Feature---Waiting-on-External-Events-%28Human-Interaction%29). So basically, my Actor would raise an event to resume my orchestration. The problem being to raise an event I need to create the instance of the orchestration. How to recreate an instance of an existing orchestration. I have the orch instance id but dont see any method to get the instance of the same orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the InstanceId, raising an event is straightforward :

```
taskHubClient.RaiseEventAsync(new OrchestrationInstance() { InstanceId = instanceId }, eventName, eventData);
```

Where the taskHubClient is an Instance of the TaskHubClient class.

Receiving events is very sensitive to versioning operations. DTF orchestration only receives the event if the type that is sent through the DTF Client exactly matches the one that is defined in the orchestration definition. So I advise to thoroughly testing the event-sending logic to avoid having events registered, but not consumed.